# How to calculate Work Week based on the Next logic

Tags: sql

I would like to calculate the work week starting from the Sunday of the week in which the 01/01 of the year falls in.

For example:

01/01/2021 is Friday

so I expect that WW1 is the week starting from Sunday 27/12/2020 to 02/01/2021

DBMS: 
Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP2-CU11) (KB4527378) - 13.0.5598.27 (X64)   Nov 27 2019 18:09:22   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard 6.3  (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)

Comment: You need tag database name as well in your question

Comment: The working week starts on Sunday in Israel. It starts on different days in many other countries in the world, for example in all of western Europe and all of north America it starts on Monday.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the help of Jeff Moden

the answer is as follow

(DATEPART   (dy,    DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd,'07 Jan 1753',Cal_Date) /7*7+6,'07 Jan 1753')   )+6         )/7